# Is it a bad practice to build maven project using root

Tags: java, maven, build, continuous-integration

Is it considered a bad practice to build a maven project using root or administrator user?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to use Jenkins to build your application For Test Environment, UAT, And Production. Jenkins will allow you to use web GUI to run your maven. and there is no issue to build application using admin user, but if that policy in you company then you can set the maven_home in your .bash_profile if you use linux or using advanced setting in windows and that will allow you to use any user to build the java application.